# How to setText via a java class to a spinner

Tags: java, android

I was trying to get the data from DataAdapter and set as setText, but for the spinner i don't know how i can achieve that.

Please can someone help me?

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List list = new ArrayList();

public ListDataAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

static class LayoutHandler{
    TextView NAME,PRICE,DESCRIPTION;
    Spinner CATEGORY;
}

@Override
public void add(@Nullable Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.NAME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_name);
        layoutHandler.PRICE = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_price);
        layoutHandler.DESCRIPTION = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_description);
        layoutHandler.CATEGORY = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_category);
        row.setTag(layoutHandler);

    }else
    {
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();


    }
    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.NAME.setText(dataProvider.getName());
    layoutHandler.PRICE.setText(dataProvider.getPrice());
    layoutHandler.DESCRIPTION.setText(dataProvider.getDescription());

  //  layoutHandler.CATEGORY.setSelection(0); <-- This is where i need help! 

    return row;
}
```

Here is my dataprovider class, Also i have add values to spinner in my XML file. so spinner has values, i just want to retire the values that are already existing for the spinner. and display it

```
public class DataProvider {

private String name;
private String price;
private String description;
private String category;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public DataProvider(String name, String price, String description, String category)
{
this.name = name;
this.price = price;
this.description = description;
this.category = category;

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have the array of category?

Comment: @tejendrasingh I just wants to know how i can use setText(dataprovider.getCategory()) for the CATEGORY

Comment: for (int position = 0; position < category.size(); position++) {
                                            if (category.get(position).getCategoryName().equalsIgnoreCase(dataProvider.getCategory)) {
                                                layoutHandler.DESCRIPTION.setSelection(position);
                                            }
                                        }

Comment: @bhuvaneshwaranvellingiri Thanks for the comment, where i should use that code? i'm new sorry to ask a newbie question

Comment: first need setadapter to spinner an array value. after this step can do in your  adapter inside get view method.

Comment: @bhuvaneshwaranvellingiri I have set values to the spinner using XML file. I'm updating the question with my dataprovider class. please let me know what i should change

Comment: String[] categoryArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);for (int position = 0; position < categoryArray.length(); position++) { if (categoryArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase(dataProvider.getCategory)) { layoutHandler.DESCRIPTION.setSelection(position); } }

Comment: @bhuvaneshwaranvellingiri I still have no clue where to insert that code

Comment: @bhuvaneshwaranvellingiri Thanks again, can you tell me what should i use for getResources(). and (R.array.testArray) ? both are showing in red color.

Comment: @bhuvaneshwaranvellingiri I have added the array code to my 1st code, please check.

Comment: that's not an array only model is there? where is array xml?

Comment: can u find array xml

Answer (score 0):

```js
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.NAME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_name);
            layoutHandler.PRICE = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_price);
            layoutHandler.DESCRIPTION = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_description);
            layoutHandler.CATEGORY = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_category);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);

        }else
        {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();


        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.NAME.setText(dataProvider.getName());
        layoutHandler.PRICE.setText(dataProvider.getPrice());
        layoutHandler.DESCRIPTION.setText(dataProvider.getDescription());


    String[] categoryArray=context.getResources().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourarrayxmlfileName);
for (int pos = 0; pos < categoryArray.length(); pos++) 
{
 if (categoryArray[pos].equalsIgnoreCase(dataProvider.getCategory)) 
 {
 layoutHandler.DESCRIPTION.setSelection(pos);
 } 
} 
        return row;
    }
```